# Unable to setup Agora Recording SDK

Tags: agora.io

I am trying to setup Agora recording setup, I have complied the samples provided in bundle and trying to run them. I am getting following exception where code is unable to find recording.dll
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no recording in

```
java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
        at io.agora.recording.RecordingSDK.<clinit>(RecordingSDK.java:24)
```

Comment: From the error hint, it looks like you did not follow the tutorial? I have it no such error before. You might need to check this out:
https://docs.agora.io/en/2.3.1/addons/Recording/Quickstart%20Guide/recording_cpp?platform=C%2B%2B It also might be your env. My java version is 1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look like an Agora error rather a Java error. The function is not finding a dependent method in its link path, you can check which function its failing on, and then check if you have a path mismatch in your compilation path
You can do java -XshowSettings:properties -version and then look at the value of java.library.path to see the library paths.

Comment: Thanks Sid, Some how there is no library in the example which code is trying to load, for the instance I switched to default c code